# How to map an element from the list to a single element in Tibco?

Tags: tibco, tibco-designer

I obtain a list of elements from the JDBC. And then I have to map an element from the returned list to another single element of a different system. Could someone help, please ? I tried for-each, but couldn't handle it. Any hints would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the output of your JDBC query is something like this records.A and records is repeating.

You can use the following syntax records[1].A to map the first value of the list to a non repeating elements, or if you have another fields B returned by your query and want to select the data depending on B value you can do something like this :  records[B=123].A, in that second example the first record found with B=123 will be mapped to your target element.